# USB hub not working at -40degC

Tags: digital-logic

I have a TUSB8041I industrial rated USB hub which is expected to work at -40 to +85degC.

I have tried everything I could.

Power sequence, reset sequence, oscillator startup OK.

It happens on 1 out of 10 boards, and happens only at -40 to -30 side. It works at room temperature, no problem.

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: If you gradually warm it from -40 does it naturally start working again without a shove?

Comment: also are you sure you are testing at -40C quite a few chambers control are POOR! put a thermalcoupler in there to confirm. Also are the boards conformally coated? mitigate ice forming

Comment: Is the oscillator starting?  Crystal oscillators can be tricky things over temperature, and people often get it wrong.  To the point where the place I worked where things needed to work down to -40, it was policy to just slap an oscillator on the board.  If I were you and had a spectrum analyzer, I'd just lay a loop over the board in the vicinity of the oscillator and look for a peak at the right frequency.

Comment: Maybe that 1 board is broken?

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @TimW, first item of suspicion is the oscillator. Especially if it works at -40°C but will not start up after soaking.

The [selected crystal](https://ecsxtal.com/store/pdf/ecx-32.pdf)'s ESR meets the minimum requirements, but the load capacitances are a bit on the light side. The crystal calls for 12pF load, so about 22pF would be closer.

Replacing it with a packaged oscillator or a resonator (not sure a typical resonator would be acceptable accuracy-wise) would likely improve things.

---

If it's not the oscillator then it's probably inside the chip and nothing  you can do except talk to the manufacturer. Typically they don't actually test the chips over the whole temperature range, of course, but depend on parameters they can measure cheaply/quickly to assure it will work over the specified range.